# Check if string contains the substring's sequence of characters in order, but not necessarily right next to each other

Tags: java, c++, string, algorithm

Given two strings, return true if the first string contains the second string's sequence of characters in order, but not necessarily right next to each other.

For example,  String : "I am hungry and want food right now", Substring: "mto". The substring where o comes before t in the sentence does not count, they have to be in order but not necessarily right next to each other.

I'm not really looking for code, just in general how would you solve this problem!

Comment: Do you mean [subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence)?

Comment: Check the indexes of each character of second string in the first string and write comparision logic.

Comment: I'd iterate over the first string, noting when a character in it matched the first as-yet-unmatched character in the second. Pretty much exactly what I'd do with pencil and paper.

Answer (score 11):

Usually when you first encounter a problem, you should evaluate how you yourself would solve the problem before considering how you would program a computer to do so.

If you try and solve your example problem yourself, you'll most likely start with the first character in the second string, 'm', and search for the first appearance of that character in the string. Once you find the 'm' at the 3rd index position, you'll then evaluate from the 4th index on to find the next letter in the substring. You'll continue to evaluate until one of two things happen:

1. You cannot find one of the letters. This means that the result is `false`.
2. You run out of letters in the substring. This means that the result is `true`.

If you understand how to solve the problem yourself, it's just a matter of breaking the solution down into steps.

You didn't ask for it, but in the off chance it makes it more clear, here's a simple method to solve the problem:

```
public static boolean sub(String string, String substring) {
    // Keep track of our position in the string.
    int index = 0;

    // Iterate through all of the characters in the substring.
    for (char character : substring.toCharArray()) {
        // Find the current character starting from the last character we stopped on.
        index = string.indexOf(character, index);
        // If the method returned -1, the character was not found, so the result is false.
        if (index == -1)
            return false;
    }

    // If we reach this point, that means all characters were found, so the result is true.
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple implementation would be like

> Traverse both strings from one side to other. If find a matching character, move ahead in both strings. Otherwise move ahead only in s2.

```
bool isSubSequence(std::string s1, std::string s2) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.length() && j < s1.length(); ++i)
        if (s1[j] == s2[i])
            ++j;
    return j == s1.length();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest to use regular expressions for solving this.
Convert your substring to a valid java regular expression.
Example `mto` can be converted into some thing like this `.*\m.*\t.*\o.*`
and then you can use java `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

(Note : The `.*` in regex represents any character zero or more times. The `\` preceding the character indicates the regex parser to consider the characters' literal value)

Answer (score 2):

Just use O(N) greedy algorithm maybe?

As you say you do not need code, I describe the steps as following:
Let `S` be the string and `P` be the pattern

1. Maintain a pointer `PT` to `P`, initially pointing at the front of `P`
2. For each character in `S`, check if `S[i]` equals to the character in `P` pointing by the `PT`
3. If yes, move `PT` to next character of `P`, if it is last character you found it

Answer (score 1):

You will have to search the string one Substring character at a time. Since you said you didn't need code, I'll try to explain how in words (with some Java API calls for reference).

For each character in the Substring, find the first occurrence of that character in String (in this case, 'm', then 't', then 'o'). You can do this with a call to `String.indexOf(String char)`. Keep track of the index that character is found and when you search String for the next character (in this case 't'), look in the subset of String starting at that index using `String.substring(idx, -1).indexOf(String char)`. The -1 will search from the index of the previously found character ('m') until the end of the string.

Keep iterating though the characters of Substring, and one of two things will happen. The first is that you will not find the character in the subset of String, which means that the Substring is not in there in order. The second possibility is that you will come to the end of Substring and all the characters will have been found in order.

Answer (score -1):

```
Q 1 : Substring Validation
Determine whether the second array is a subsequence of the first array, given two non-empty sequences of integers.
write a method.
A subsequence of a sequence is not necessarily contiguous in the sequence, but the same as they appear in the sequence.
is a sequenced set of numbers. For example, the numbers 1, 3, 4 form a substring of the array [1, 2, 3, 4], and
So are the numbers [2, 4]. A single number in a sequence and the sequence itself are not valid subsequences of the sequence.
Example Input
array= [5, 1, 22, 25, 6, -1, 8, 10]
sequence= [1, 6, -1, 10]
Sample Output
true
public static bool Validate Subarray(List<int> array, List<int> sequence) {
// the code will be written here
return false;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).